# メソッドを用いた配列の呼び出し方、配列の要素への代入の仕方を教えてください

Tags: java

Javaの配列のプログラムについて質問です。

以下のプログラムで、hairetsu()メソッドと、mainメソッドの2つを用意しました。
配列自体を、hairetsuメソッドで作成し、mainメソッドで、引数を指定して、hairetsuメソッドを呼び出しています。

今回ですと、mainメソッドでfor文を使って、全ての配列の要素に、「あ」を代入したいのですが、以下のコンパイルエラーが出てしまい、実行できません。今回のように、配列のメソッドを作り、他のメソッドで呼び出して、値を代入するには、どうすればいいでしょうか？

**エラー内容:**

```
ample_hairetsu1.java:14: エラー: 予期しない型
                hairetsu(i,m)="あ";
                        ^
  期待値: 変数
  検出値:    値
エラー1個
```

**ソースコード:**

```
public class Sample_hairetsu1{
    public static String[][] hairetsu(int i, int m) {
        String[][] hairetsu = new String[9][9];
        System.out.print(hairetsu[i][m]);
        return hairetsu;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for (int m = 0; m < 9; m++){
                hairetsu(i, m) = "あ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**実行環境:**
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mainメソッドでfor文を使って、全ての配列の要素に、「あ」を代入したい

ということからすると、

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] hairetsu = new String[9][9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            hairetsu[i][j] = "あ";
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("[%d][%d]: %s", i, j, hairetsu[i][j]));
        }
    }
}
```

こういう感じのことがやりたかったのかなと思いますが、`hairetsu[i][j]` と `hairetsu(i, j)` では、前者は変数なので左辺で代入可能ですが、後者はメソッドなので、左辺値としてそれに対する代入はできません。

> 配列のメソッドを作り、他のメソッドで呼び出して、値を代入する

これをメソッド化したいのであれば、代入部分のループをメソッドとして独立させると

```
public static String[][] fillAll(String filler, int size1, int size2) {
    String[][] hairetsu = new String[size1][size2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            hairetsu[i][j] = filler;
        }
    }
    
    return hairetsu;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] hairetsu = fillAll("あ", 9, 9);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("[%d][%d]: %s", i, j, hairetsu[i][j]));
        }
    }
}
```

一例としてこんな感じです。

Comment: mainメソッドで、新たにString[][] hairetsu を用意して、fillAll()メソッドの返り値を代入しているのでしょうか？なぜmainメソッドで新たに配列を用意する必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: @DaisukeOgawa `new` しているわけではないので、「新たに別のオブジェクトを生成して」いるわけではありません。オブジェクト実体は同じものですが、名前空間のスコープの問題で、main 側は main 側でその名前空間のスコープ内における名前 `hairetu` を fillAll から戻ってきたオブジェクトに対して付与している形になります。